Unable to use uploaded font .TTF Zebra printer
I tried to upload roboto.TTF font to my zebra printer(ZT610 Firmware Version: V96.21.30Z)
using this ~DUd:o.X,s,data
Here is completed command

The data i convert from .TTF to Base64. The uploading is success. Refer to below pic:

but when i try to use the font . zebra printer unable to print the font. What i did wrongly. Really Appreciate the help.
Here is the zpl command that i am using:
^XA
^FO50,50
^A@N,50,E:ROB002.TTF
^FDSample^FS
^FO50,100
^A@N,80,E:ROB002.TTFp
^FDSample^FS
^FO50,150
^A@N,100,E:ROB002.TTF
^FDSample^FS
^XZ

Updated ~DU using .TTF to hexadecimal also not working.
~DUE:ROB002,252966,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....


You need to provide an example of zpl code that doesn't work.

Hi @MarkWarren, i already provide the zpl code that doest't not work. Thanks you for your time.

The information I can find on the ~DU command indicates that it wants the font data in hexadecimal, NOT Base64.

Hi @jasonharper, Thanks for replying. I already change the font to hexadecimal also not working. The printer stuck when i upload using ~DU.

Might be something wrong with the conversion. I would recommend using the font converter you can find in ZebraNet Bridge. It's free and you'll get a ZPL file you can upload straight to the printer.
